# How do I access the json from the body of a POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Unable to retrieve the json body from POST or PUT in my api controller class

The routing seems to be correct as the code clearly falls into the correct functions and the "id" value (from the URI) is accessible in the PUT and GET method input parameters. Not only is the value of the "value" parameter not populating, the body does not even seem to be in the request object.

My headers include Content-Type: application/json and Content-Length: n.

I have gone so far as setting up an async method to retrieve the value from Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync, but that was also empty.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace API.Controllers
{
        public class ValuesController : ApiController
        {
                // GET api/values
                public IEnumerable<string> Get()
                {
                        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
                }

                // GET api/values/5
                public string Get(int id)
                {
                        return "value";
                }

                // POST api/values
                public void Post([FromBody]string value)
                {
                }

                // PUT api/values/5
                public string Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
                {
                        string returnValue = "";

                        if(value != null)
                        {
                                if (value.Length > 0)
                                {
                                        returnValue = value;
                                } else
                                {
                                        returnValue = "No data";
                                }
                        } else
                        {
                                returnValue = "No data";
                        }

                        return returnValue;
                }

                // DELETE api/values/5
                public void Delete(int id)
                {
                }
        }
}
```

When calling the PUT method, I would expect to get "5" (the value if "id" in the URI) followed by a reflection of the json body sent. Instead, I get "5 No data" as the value of the "value" is Nothing, as it is when making a POST call.

Comment: When I have this issue (Which I do just about every time I do similar things) The problem is not actually in my controller, more with making the request incorrectly.  How are you doing that?

Comment: @Hursey: I use Postman. URI: `https://localhost:44349/api/values/5`, body: `{"Test1":"String1","Test2": 2}`, headers: `Content-Type:application/json, Content-Length:44`